# Is it possible to include scipy.stat function in pandas aggregate function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

num  = np.random.randint(20,100, size=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(num, columns=["Weight"])

df.agg([np.sum, np.std, st.sem])
```

> i am getting following error.
>
> RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice keepdims=keepdims
>
> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> ----> 1 df.agg([np.sum, np.std, st.sem])

**Is there any way to include scipy.stats function in pandas aggregate?**

for example to get the geometric mean `scipy.stats.gmean()` or harmonic mean `scipy.stats.hmean()` (function only available in scipy.stats) can i use it in pandas df.agg() function?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to do as below

df.agg(['sum','std','sem'])

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But what for  'mode',  'hmean'? is there any way to include the function which are only available in Scipy.stats ?

Comment: you just need to add the keyword 'mean'

Comment: Hi this will calculate the arithmetic mean, my question is what if I want to calculate the **geometric mean** ```scipy.stats.gmean()``` or **harmonic mean** ```scipy.stats.hmean()``` (function only available in scipy.stats) can i use it in pandas df.agg() function?

Comment: I found nothing on the official documentation page. The below command provides us a possible method that can be applied to the data frame. print(dir(DataFrame)).                                                                                        So, I believe, there is no method in Pandas that enables us to calculate geometric and harmonic means within agg function.                                                                      
from scipy.stats.mstats import gmean
gmean(df.Weight)